# One Channel Relay Board with NRF24 / WiFi connectivity with built in power supply

Tags: relay, wireless, esp8266, nrf24l01, smart

I have been looking out for a board which has a one channel relay along with some wireless connectivity such as a NRF24 module or a Wemos D1 Mini attached to it aong with a built in power supply. Is any such module available and if not is there any custom module whose gerber file I can use ? I need this to create any bulb socket or plug socket into a smart plug or smart light.

Comment: Why not just purchase an smart light bulb? Could you clarify specifications and application?

Comment: @Ernesto I do have a smart bulb which can only be operated by the company's app or by alexa or google home, I do not have any access to any APIs using which I can operate it with a let's say a python code or so. the bulb I am mentioning here is a Halonix Prism

Comment: It wasn't clear, but it seems you want a smart bulb that can be controlled via a computer running python or similar. A quick google search lead me to LIFX bulbs as having accessible API, although there's probable several other options